# My Python implementation of the Gale-Shapely Algorithm is producing incorrect results

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, bipartite

Good day! I'm trying to implement the Gale-Shapley algorithm in python. The purpose of the algorithm is to take a list of men and a list of women (both lists are of equal length), as well as the list of preferences for each man and woman. It is also known as the Stable Marriage algorithm. The pseudocode is as follows.

While there exists an unmarried man:

1. Pick an arbitrary unmarried man M
2. Choose the top woman W from his list to whom he hasn't proposed yet
3. If W is free or prefers M over her current husband, then marry M and W

My Python implementation of the Gale-Shapley algorithm is producing the result [1, 2, None, 0] when:

n= 4,
menPreferences =[[0, 1, 3, 2], [0, 2, 3, 1], [1, 0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 1, 2]]

womenPreferences = [[3, 1, 2, 0], [3, 1, 0, 2], [0, 3, 1, 2], [1, 0, 3, 2]])

Here is my code:

```
def stableMatching(n, menPreferences, womenPreferences):

# Do not change the function definition line.



  # Initially, all n men are unmarried

  unmarriedMen = list(range(n))

  # None of the men has a spouse yet, we denote this by the value None

  manSpouse = [None] * n

  # None of the women has a spouse yet, we denote this by the value None

  womanSpouse = [None] * n

  # Each man made 0 proposals, which means that

  # his next proposal will be to the woman number 0 in his list

  nextManChoice = [0] * n

# While there exists at least one unmarried man:

  while unmarriedMen:

    # Pick an arbitrary unmarried man

    he = unmarriedMen[0]

    # Store his ranking in this variable for convenience

    hisPreferences = menPreferences[he]

    # Find a woman to propose to

    she = hisPreferences[nextManChoice[he]]

    # Store her ranking in this variable for convenience

    herPreferences = womenPreferences[she]

    # Find the present husband of the selected woman (it might be None)

    currentHusband = womanSpouse[she]


    #Variable that helps us to keep track of when a man is made single

    divorcedMan = None

    #The man currently making the proposal (Incrementing Variable)

    manProposing = 0



    #For the current list of married men:

    while manProposing < len(unmarriedMen):

      #Chooses the next man to make a proposal

      he = unmarriedMen[manProposing]

      #Establishing the parameters aka the preferences for the man

      #currently making the proposal

      # Store his ranking in this variable for convenience

      hisPreferences = menPreferences[he]

      # Find a woman to propose to

      she = hisPreferences[nextManChoice[he]]

      # Store her ranking in this variable for convenience

      herPreferences = womenPreferences[she]

      # Find the present husband of the selected woman (it might be None)

      currentHusband = womanSpouse[she]


      #If the next preference for this man is not married

      if currentHusband == None:
        #The woman becomes married to this man

        womanSpouse[she] = he

        #The man becomes married to this woman

        manSpouse[he] = she

        #The index of the currently matched man is incremented

          if (len(unmarriedMen) - nextManChoice[he]) >= 2:

            nextManChoice[he] += 1

            #This indicates that the man is no longer single

            unmarriedMen[he] = -1

            #The next man is moved on to

            manProposing += 1



        else:

        #If the man proposing making a proposal is more preferred by her

          if herPreferences.index(he) < herPreferences.index(currentHusband):

              #She leaves her current husband

            divorcedMan = currentHusband

            manSpouse[divorcedMan] = None

            #The proposing becomes her husband

            womanSpouse[she] = he

            #currentHusband = he

            #She becomes his wife

            manSpouse[he] = she

            #The index of the currently matched man is incremented

            if (len(unmarriedMen) - nextManChoice[he]) >= 2:

              nextManChoice[he] += 1

            #This indicates that the man is no longer single

            unmarriedMen[he] = -1

            #This will look at the next man that is to do the next proposal

            manProposing += 1

            #The new divorcee man is placed back in the list

            for man in unmarriedMen:

            if (unmarriedMen.index(man) == divorcedMan) and (man == -1):

              unmarriedMen[unmarriedMen.index(man)] = divorcedMan

              break

            else:
                 if (divorcedMan < man):

              unmarriedMen.insert(unmarriedMen.index(man), divorcedMan)

              break


            #Resetting the variable divorcedMan

            divorcedMan = None

    #Variable for temporarily holding newly formed list of married men

    temp = []

    #Forms new list of married men

    for bachelor in unmarriedMen:

      if bachelor != -1:

          temp.append(bachelor)

    unmarriedMen = temp

 return manSpouse
```

I'm struggling to find the logical errors in my code. Can somebody help me in pinpointing them? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: When you run this using a debugger, what is the first point it behaves differently than you expected?

Comment: What is expected output?